# passing value from parent to child not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using Vuu.js, I'm trying to pass a value from parent to child component. I have this working fine with a provided example. But when I change the name, it stops working. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. My understanding on props is limited, i'm still trying to get me head around it.

**Working Example:**

https://codepen.io/sdras/pen/788a6a21e95589098af070c321214b78

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <child :text="message"></child>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['text'],
  template: `<div>{{ text }}</div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'hello mr. magoo'
    }
  }
});
```

**Non Working Example:**

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <child :myVarName="message"></child>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['myVarName'],
  template: `<div>{{ myVarName }}</div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'hello mr. magoo'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your parent template

```
<div id="app">
  <child :myVarName="message"></child>
</div>
```

replace

```
<child :myVarName="message"></child>
```

with

```
<child :my-var-name="message"></child>
```

Additionally you can refer [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) to get insights of casing.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. It won't allow camel case? I'll need to do some reading up within the docs to understand this further. Thanks again. Will mark as correct when it allows me.

Answer (score 3):

Leave everything as is in your updated example EXCEPT in the **HTML** change "myVarName" to "my-var-name" - this is done by default by Vue and within the js you can use the camelCased version myVarName still.